# VBA - draw in numbers from one sheet and get data from another

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a VBA to draw data from one sheet to another, but am stuck on something.
I only need some of the data in the original sheet (let's call it s1), in particular, I need data between two rows.
I have these rows written down in another sheet (s2), so I know exactly between which rows I need the data from. As you may expect there are multiple rows between which I need the data.

The problem is now that I am trying to write a VBA that is able to look up these rows in my row sheet (s2), and then goes to the sheet in which all my original data is contained (s1), and then draws out the data between the two rows into a third sheet (s3).
I have not been able to make it draw in the numbers from s2 (can't seem to work out how to tell it that it is these two rows between which I need the data, but from another sheet), and currently have to input the row numbers myself, which is really tedious, since the dataset is large!

Any help would be much appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: It might help if you could construct a simplified example in code that demonstrates the problem and can be adapted to demonstrate solutions.

Comment: You might want to share the code you have tried along with some sample data for s1, s2 and s3

Comment: Also you might want to [check this out](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) and then revise your question accordingly.

Comment: In s2 do you have two actual *row numbers*, or two text/number values which have to be matched against s1 ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the .find option.

You could use something like this:

findrow = w1.Cells.Find(what:="Content", MatchCase:=False).Row

An more extensive example would help

Answer (score 0):

Just break down your problem into smaller steps.

You can assign a value on a sheet using cell references:

```
Sheets("S1").Cells(iRow, iCol) = Value
'or 
Sheets("S3").Cells(2, 10) = Sheets("S2").Cells(2, 10)
```

You can use Sheets("S1").Range("J" & iRow) or Range("J2").

If there are conditions that need to be met for something to happen, use If statements.

```
If (Value 1 < Value 2) Then 
    Sheets("S3").Cells(2, 10) = Sheets("S2").Cells(2, 10)
Else
    Sheets("S3").Cells(2, 10) = Sheets("S1").Cells(2, 10)
End If
```

Without more information about the specific choices you are using to determine which rows to copy and from which sheet, it's hard to say.  But you can do things in smaller batches or copy whole ranges, by looping.

```
Dim iRow As Integer

'This would copy all the data from Sheet("S1").Range("J1:J20) to Sheet "S3".
For iRow = 1 to 20
    Sheets("S3").Cells(iRow, 10) = Sheets("S1").Cells(iRow, 10)
Next iRow
```

You could insert an If statement into each row, inside the loop to see if a certain criteria is met, and then decide which sheet in which to copy the data.